# Double click event in android

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

How to implement double click event in android without using gesturedetector?

Comment: What's a double click on mobile screen?

Comment: Why can't you use the gesturedetector?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you mean double tap you have to use [GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener.html).

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure all the code there does is determine if the second click was within a certain time of the first click, otherwise treat it as a second click. That's how I would do it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

just use setOnTouchListener to record the first and second click time. If they are very close, determine it as a double click. Like this,

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private final String DEBUG_TAG= "MyActivity";
    private long firstClick;
    private long lastClick;
    private int count; // to count click times

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Button mButton= (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button);
        mButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        // if the second happens too late, regard it as first click
                        if (firstClick != 0 && System.currentTimeMillis() - firstClick > 300) {
                            count = 0;
                        }
                        count++;
                        if (count == 1) {
                            firstClick = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        } else if (count == 2) {
                            lastClick = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            // if these two clicks is closer than 300 millis second 
                            if (lastClick - firstClick < 300) {
                                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"a double click happened");
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look here, this is library in jar for listening touch gestures, implement and work )
https://github.com/NikolayKolomiytsev/zTouch

Answer (score 0):

Look at the source code for `GestureDetector` and copy the bits you need (specifically, look at the `isConsideredDoubleTap` method)

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/GestureDetector.java

Comment: i am using chart application if i click the point for double click it will go to another activity.if i am used gesture detector if i click anywhere it will go to other activity