# Android Studio - How to perform doubleClick in Kotlin?

Tags: android, double-click, ondoubleclick

A boring thing when some more advanced technologies impose their standards is to have to do with the "double click" to perform an action. But what I'm looking for is an easy way to implement it without having to rewrite the code a thousand times.

I would like to implement `double click` in my project using Kotlin.
Could someone help me?
Thanks in Advance

just to know: I would like a way to understand how to do double click or to prevent  that user do a doubleclick

Comment: Do you want to implement a double-click listener of just perform two clicks with the determined delay?

Comment: I would to do both :-) do you know some Library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I implemented this [library](https://gitlab.com/developerdeveloperdeveloper/androidutilslibrary) using Kotlin, you can just define the doubleClick property and override single and double click methods, and finally add it to setOnClickListener of your button

```
val doubleClick = DoubleClick(object : DoubleClickListener {
    override fun onSingleClickEvent(view: View?) {
        // DO STUFF SINGLE CLICK
    }

    override fun onDoubleClickEvent(view: View?) {
       // DO STUFF DOUBLE CLICK
    }
})

button.setOnClickListener(doubleClick)
```

https://gitlab.com/developerdeveloperdeveloper/androidutilslibrary

Comment: Sound Like good. I've implemented it and work perfectly Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4):

you can use this code its like double click if you dont like it you can read about Gesture Listener.

```
var doubleClick: Boolean? = false
yourview.setOnClickListener {
        if (doubleClick!!) {
            //Code here when they double click
        }
        doubleClick = true
        Handler().postDelayed({ doubleClick = false }, 2000)
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

GestureDetector contains [OnDoubleTapListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener) which allows us to handle double-clicks. It is the easiest way to implement a double-click listener. 
Also, you can try to find existing solutions like these:

https://github.com/pedromassango/doubleClick

https://github.com/fkirc/DoubleClickListener-for-Android

There are several posts on StackOverflow related to this theme. Please, check them.

[how to implement double click in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971224/how-to-implement-double-click-in-android)

[How to detect double click event for buttons in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28680558/how-to-detect-double-click-event-for-buttons-in-android)

[Double click event in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245607/double-click-event-in-android)

According to clicks generating, I suppose you can call [performClick()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#performClick()) method several times with delay.